# make slide:hover the overflow the block that is below the slick container

Tags: containers, slider, overflow, margin, slick.js

[1]I'm using slick slide. And I need to make slide:hover the overflow the block that is below the slick container

I try make margin-minus and padding-minus - not helping. position absolute also not helping. Have no idea what to do

Here the screenshot of what I need
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Bjhbs83W1TYVkPevup_76TKd-1fDwsS6/view?usp=share_link

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.